# Are wallet addresses in the crypto exchange website actual ethereum accounts?

Tags: wallets, accounts, exchanges

a newbie here,
I am trying to understand how ethereum based CEX's work. Users create accounts/wallet addresses (not email-linked user accounts) on the exchange. **Are those addresses actual ethereum accounts from the mainnet?**

I am asking this because this exchange has about 1000 users, but when I type eth.accounts in geth console, it shows only one ethereum account, which I assume to be the exchange account. **Shouldn't there be 1000 accounts? How does the exchange handle it when a user deposits/withdraws from the exchange to the external account in the mainnet?**

Answer (score 0):

If you can send funds to it from mainnet, so it is an Ethereum account.

(I received this reply in another community.)